# How to pass a javascript variable in an id of a div (into twig loop)?

Tags: javascript, html, twig

How to pass a javascript variable in an id of a div (into twig loop) ?

*Here is what I tried, without success:*

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     id = 0;
</script>
{% for element in parent.elements %}
     <div id="mydiv">
         <script>
         document.getElementById('mydiv').id('mydiv'+id);
         id++;
         </script>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

*Desired result (if 3 elements) :*

```
<div id="mydiv0">
</div>
<div id="mydiv1">
</div>
<div id="mydiv2">
</div>
```

Comment: Why you would use js for it?! Couldn't you just print it with php? Also, js will start when page/dom is loaded (after php is executed), so there is no too much sense to place it into template loop...

Comment: because i use twig template

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The twig code is executed in the server, when the php is trying to create an html page that is then sent to the client. Then, the client (browser) executes the javascript. So, when the javascript runs you already have your three divs created, all with id 'mydiv'. Since HTML cannot have several elements with the same id, this HTML is not valid.

What you want is to have access to the index in the twig for loop. You can use this with the [loop.index](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/tags/for.html#the-loop-variable) variable.

```
{% for element in parent.elements %}
    <div id="mydiv{{loop.index}}">         
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

You can also use `loop.index0`, if it is important that your ids start with 'mydiv0'.